# Django search in the database

Tags: python, django

I use MySQL for the production server and SQLite for the testing local server for my django application.

I've a model like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
```

I've implemented a search feature in my application for searching product.
I use this command: `Product.objects.filter(name__contains = text)`

But in this way, if I search a white space `" "`, the application returns me every product with a space in the name. It's a bit ugly, and also if I search a single char, for example `a` it returns all name that contains `a`. Is there a way to search only 'single full word'?

Comment: Probably you can include some client side validation which would not submit unless the user submits 'n' characters(n can be configured by you).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#regex

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

```
pattern= r"\b%s\b" % text
Product.objects.filter(name__regex = pattern)
```

Comment: What about it?  You can easily benchmark each one using `timeit`.